# Get-Service не выводит список сервисов, если скрипт запустить через scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, планировщик-задач

Windows Server 2012R2. Обычный пользователь (не администратор). В консоли powershell Get-Service выводит список сервисов, а если тот же скрипт запустить от имени этого же пользователя, но через scheduler, то выдается пустой результат. Никаких ошибок. Проверил на 2 серверах. Кто сталкивался, как победить?

Проверял, например, так:

```
"test" > C:\1\1.txt
Get-Service > C:\1\2.txt
Get-Service | Out-File C:\1\3.txt
exit
```

В файле 1.txt запись test появилась.
А в 2.txt и 3.txt пусто.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Windows Vista введен запрет на выполнение определённых запросов, в том числе `Get-Service`, в планировщике  под правами обычного пользователя, даже если в интерактивном режиме ему это позволено. Даже под правами администратора сведения о некоторых сервисах в планировщике таким образом не получить.

Простое решение: запустить ваш скрипт под правами администратора.

Сложное решение: поиграться с [security descriptor'ами](https://blogs.msmvps.com/erikr/2007/09/26/set-permissions-on-a-specific-service-windows/), разрешив проверять статус части сервисов и обычному пользователю. Есть даже [весьма подробное пошаговое описание](https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/Accessing-service-status-from-.html), как это сделать.